# JSON returning duplicates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I try to draw data from a database, my javascript is returning the JSON twice. **Why would my JSON return this way?**

PHP:

```
<?php
require ('functions.inc');
dbconn(); //establish my db connection
mysql_selectdb("acts");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from actInfo");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
     $name = $row[ActName];
}
$json=json_encode($name);
echo $json;
?>
```

Javascript:

```
function getActNames(){
if (windows.XMLHttpRequest)
{
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
     var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
     var parseV = JSON.parse(json);
     $("#somediv").append(parseV);
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","PHP/actMgmt.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And I'm calling it in HTML via the following:

```
<p class = "button" onclick= "getActNames();return false;">Some Button </p>
```

My JSON call is creating 2x the requested records. SO instead of getting the following:

```
["act1","act2","act3"]
```

I am getting:

```
["act1,"act2","act3"]["act1","act2","act3"]
```

It seems that every time, its called twice.

ALSO, when I just go to the PHP page, it only returns the following like I expect:

```
["act1","act2","act3"]
```

**EDIT

var_dump($name) outputs:
 array(6)=>{ [0]=>string(4)"act1" [1]=> string(4)"act2" [2]=> string(4)"act3"}

**EDIT

console.log(xmlhttp.responseText) gives me:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
["act1","act2","act3"]
```

Comment: all of the articles in this table are unique for that column

Comment: Can you `var_dump($name)` and output that?

Comment: Hey Shivanshu, thanks for the info but I already have separate pages. Using the javascript as an intermediate between my PHP page that gets the data and my HTML page that presents it.

Comment: Added var_dump to question.

Comment: Can you also console.log(xmlhttp.responseText) ans show here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it now. I would, in the future, HIGHLY suggest you use a framework like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to avoid this. Writing your own AJAX function tends to lead to problems like this.
Your AJAX call isn't checking for a proper status. It's just looking for any return at all. As such, every time you get a packet, it kicks off your anonymous function.

Change your code to this and you should get only one array

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
     var parseV = JSON.parse(json);
     $("#somediv").append(parseV);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, gave it a shot. Same result.

Comment: Edited response. I bet that fixes it

Comment: Wow, I'm not that great as JS yet but I def knew I should have included that. Bit of a newb move I guess. Thanks for your help! Worked PERFECTLY.

Comment: That's a major reason why I recommend jQuery. I hate writing my own calls like this. JQ saves you the headache :)

Answer (score 0):

It is due to multiple ajax call on the same page(you can observe that as this may happen on first run), so not a solution but still you can escape from the current scenario, by making seperate php and html(containing ajax) pages,

Comment: Can you tell me where I am making the duplicate calls here? I have checked and no other JS function in my scripts call this.

Comment: Intentionally you are not, Its default !

Comment: What is the best way to just get the single result? <<Thats an answer I'd +1 :)

Comment: as I said earlier, just code ajax+html on a separate page and php on a separate page, just give it a try at least !

Comment: I have an html page, a separate JS script file, and a separate PHP file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: combine js+html ! 
overall you will be having just 2 files, a .php and a .html !

Comment: I have several different javascript/jquery functions I want to use. Wouldn't it be unorganized to do that? Different calls on each page, sometimes reusing them? I dont mean to offend, I'm just curious what other programmers do.

Answer (score 0):

according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) the `onreadystatechange` event is triggered every time the `readyState` changes.

which means in every request cycle it is called more then once with the possible options:

```
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready
```

so what you need to do is:

```
function getActNames() {
    if (windows.XMLHttpRequest) {
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        // Called when the request finished successfully and response is ready.
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
             var parseV = JSON.parse(json);
             $("#somediv").append(parseV);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","PHP/actMgmt.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

seeing as you are using jQuery I strongly advise you use the jQuery ajax as shown:

```
$.post("PHP/actMgmt.php", { pram1: "value1" }, function( data ) {
    $("#somediv").append(data);
}, "json");
```

Hope this helps.